# Can't figure out how to pivot and merge these results

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a query that returns data that looks like.

```
PackageName  SiteLocation  Visible
Package1     SiteOne       1
Package1     SiteTwo       0
Package1     SiteFour      1
Package2     SiteThree     1
```

What I am wanting is the data to look like

```
PackageName  SiteOne  SiteTwo  SiteThree  SiteFour
Package1     1        0        NULL       1
Package2     Null     Null     1          NULL
```

I did a pivot on Site but the results I get look like

```
PackageName  SiteOne  SiteTwo  SiteThree  SiteFour
Package1     1        NULL     NULL       NULL
Package1     NULL     0        NULL       NULL
Package1     NULL     NULL     NULL       1
Package2     Null     Null     1          NULL
```

Is there a way to merge pivot on site then merge the results of PackageName?

The query that returns this data is a simple query that just joins together foreign keys to turn SiteLocation into something meaningful instead of a FK_Id

Comment: please post your query, if you have additional columns in your query that are not needed for the `PIVOT` then you will get this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your actual query, I am guessing that you have additional fields in your query that is breaking your `PIVOT`.  If those are the only fields returned by your query, then it should be working:

```
select *
from
(
  select packagename,
    sitelocation,
    visible
  from yourquery
) x
pivot
(
  max(visible)
  for sitelocation in ([SiteOne], [SiteTwo], [SiteThree], [SiteFour])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91096/2)

But if you have other fields included in your results, then the `PIVOT` will not work properly:

```
select *
from
(
  select packagename,
    sitelocation,
    visible, 
    breakit
  from yourquery
) x
pivot
(
  max(visible)
  for sitelocation in ([SiteOne], [SiteTwo], [SiteThree], [SiteFour])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cb78/2)